# onActivityResult called immediately on startActivityForResult

Tags: android, react-native, onactivityresult, react-native-bridge

I am trying to get results from native activity in React Native Module. When I called `startActivityForResult` from my React Native Module, `onActivityResult` is called immediately even though the activity shows up but `RESULT_CANCELED` is immediately returned to onActivityResult().

I have followed the official guide from [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-android#getting-activity-result-from-startactivityforresult)

My Module code to start activity:

```
Activity currentActivity = getCurrentActivity();
if (currentActivity != null) {
    Intent tgIntent = new Intent(currentActivity, SecondActivity.class);
    tgIntent.setFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    currentActivity.startActivityForResult(tgIntent, REQUEST_CODE_ENROLLMENT);
}
```

I tried both of following to set activity event listener but nothing changes

```
context.addActivityEventListener(activityEventListener);
```

```
context.addActivityEventListener(this);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the "New Task" flag from the intent.

`startActivityForResult` must be under the same task as the calling activity.

According to [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20android.os.Bundle)):

> if the activity you are launching uses `Intent#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`, it will not run in your task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

Comment: thank you for response. Actually, my activity can launch multiple instances with different data, what flag should be replaced for `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`?

Comment: Default flags - without calling `setFlags`